# Why does Spring Security's RoleVoter need a prefix?

Tags: spring-security

In our application we planned to use the `RoleVoter` mechanism but we'd like to remove the `ROLE_` prefix as the security we are implementing is more *task based* than *role based*.

Technically, there is no problem for the implementation but I found in the documentation that [using the `RoleVoter` with an empty prefix should be discouraged](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html#setRolePrefix%28java.lang.String%29).

I'm wondering why?

AFAICS, the only problem is that, without the prefix, the `RoleVoter` will participate in decisions that it is not meant to (such as the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`, `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, ...) and might returns an access denied instead of an abstain.

Could you please confirm that this is the only issue with an empty prefix?

Thanks in advance
M.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. If you are using multiple voters or a custom voter then they need some way knowing which attributes they should consume. For example, if you have a `DayOfTheWeekVoter` and you have a resource defined with attributes `ROLE_USER,DAY_MONDAY` then the `RoleVoter` might vote to grant access because the user has the role "User", but the `DayOfTheWeekVoter` might deny access because it is not a Monday.

If you don't configure `RoleVoter` with a prefix then it would check if the user has the authority named "DAY_MONDAY" assigned to them, and so this scenario won't work.

If you are only interested in roles, then you can do without a prefix, or you can use expressions (such as `hasRole('user')`) which don't use a `RoleVoter`.

Comment: Hello Luke, I just upgrade Spring Boot from 1.2.2 to 1.3.2 and this started to brake for me. My Controllers have @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Edit')") and now it's starting to check for the ROLE_ prefix. Seems like your explanation of hasRole() has changed since you posted this answer because it's going through the RoleVoter. I tried to find ways to set the prefix to empty "" but none of them are working...Can you recommend another way to do this in Spring Boot 1.3.2?