# Spring Security remove RoleVoter prefix

Tags: spring, spring-security

In the project I am working we authenticate based on role ids rather than role description and this mapping is stored in the database.

My question is, How do I remove Spring Security's RoleVoter prefix to implement the design as above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring security `RoleVoter`needs a prefix in order to distinguish the granted authorities that are roles, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539162/why-does-spring-securitys-rolevoter-need-a-prefix) for further details.

If you want to change this, you can always provide your own custom `AccessDecisionManager and configure it with a custom`RoleVoter`.

This is an example of such a custom access decision manager:

```
public class MyAccessDecisionManager  extends AffirmativeBased {


    public MyAccessDecisionManager() {
        super();
        List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter>();
        RoleVoter roleVoter = new MyCustomRoleVoter();
        decisionVoters.add(roleVoter);
        AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter = new AuthenticatedVoter();
        decisionVoters.add(authenticatedVoter);
        setDecisionVoters(decisionVoters);

    }
```

And for using it in place of the default access decision manager:

```
<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="full.package.name.MyAccessDecisionManager" />

<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager">
    ...
</security:http>
```

Comment: How do I configure it in `spring-security.xml`?

Comment: The constructor AffirmativeBased() is undefined in spring security 4.1.3

Answer (score 5):

May be somebody need decision with annotation based for web application

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
protected static class GlobalSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = (AffirmativeBased)super.accessDecisionManager();
        for(AccessDecisionVoter voter: accessDecisionManager.getDecisionVoters()){
            if(voter instanceof RoleVoter){
                // do what you whant
            }
        }
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = Arrays.asList(
                new WebExpressionVoter(),
                new RoleVoter(),
                new AuthenticatedVoter()
        );
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative is to avoid prefix on attributes, for example for LDAP:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        final LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();
        ldapConfigurer.rolePrefix("");
    }
}
```

To avoid using of `ROLE_` prefix by `RoleVoter` define own `GrantedAuthorityDefaults`:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    /** Reset prefix to be empty. */
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
    }
}
```

See [How do I remove the ROLE_ prefix from Spring Security with JavaConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134121/how-do-i-remove-the-role-prefix-from-spring-security-with-javaconfig)

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 4 replace `hasRole("X")` with `hasAuthority("X")`.

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/el-access.html